# Can I open a solution without opening its documents, or clearing the user options?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a solution which, when opened, crashes VS2008.  This has happened before and I can [work around the problem by deleting the SUO file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148143).  But that clears all my other options too, in particular the set of exceptions to break on, and setting them up again is very annoying.

Is there a way to open a solution without opening its documents, or clearing the user options?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider opening Visual Studio in safe mode.  This can be done by running devenv from the command line:

```
devenv /SafeMode
```

If that will launch you, open the solution, close all windows, close the solution, close Visual Studio and restart in normal mode.  Before opening any windows, do a full rebuild.